# Tensorflow `x` and `y` must have the same dtype, even after casting to the correct type

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi all getting an error I'm not expecting when fitting a model even after casting to the correct type. Code snippet below showing the error and workflow.

```
        # print(asset_weight_dict[asset_name])
        x_train, x_val = X.iloc[train_idx], X.iloc[val_idx]
        y_train, y_val = y.iloc[train_idx], y.iloc[val_idx]
        x_train = tf.cast(x_train, tf.float32)
        x_val = tf.cast(x_val, tf.float32)
        y_train = tf.cast(y_train, tf.float32)
        y_val = tf.cast(y_val, tf.float32)
        print(x_train.info())
        print()
        print(y_train.info())
        with strategy.scope(): model = build_model(fold, dim = x_train.shape[1], weight = asset_weight_dict[asset_name])

        # SAVE BEST MODEL EACH FOLD
        sv = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('fold-%i.h5' % fold, monitor = 'val_loss', verbose = 0, save_best_only = True, save_weights_only = True, mode = 'min', save_freq = 'epoch')

        # TRAIN


        history = model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

The output of x_train and y_train info shows both are in the float32 dtype:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[-1.1736900e-18  8.4033599e-19  6.4855290e-18 ... -1.7973387e-03
  -9.7247097e-04 -8.3497784e-04]
 [-4.9040946e-03 -9.3674008e-03 -9.2475545e-03 ...  2.5425672e-03
   3.5907906e-03  3.6137134e-03]
 [-5.7132118e-03 -7.1952469e-03 -6.1273980e-03 ...  1.0056033e-02
   9.7314240e-03  9.3650799e-03]
 ...
 [ 2.7320897e-05  2.7972811e-03 -3.9492366e-03 ...  9.2556234e-03
   8.6822165e-03  9.2183622e-03]
 [-2.7372641e-03 -5.3076809e-03 -6.9548660e-03 ... -4.5336168e-03
  -3.8521911e-03 -3.2705730e-03]
 [ 1.2495884e-03  1.8994033e-03 -5.5942247e-03 ...  8.6857486e-05
  -6.3753058e-04 -5.0171453e-04]], shape=(32157, 121), dtype=float32)

tf.Tensor(
[[ 0.01257048]
 [ 0.00535373]
 [-0.00205016]
 ...
 [ 0.01012999]
 [-0.0218502 ]
 [-0.00389742]], shape=(32157, 1), dtype=float32)
```

Full error message after running showing that y (I think) is somehow being recast to int32 or I'm fundamentally missing something.

```
Input In [26], in get_Xy_and_model_for_asset(asset_name)
     49 sv = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('fold-%i.h5' % fold, monitor = 'val_loss', verbose = 0, save_best_only = True, save_weights_only = True, mode = 'min', save_freq = 'epoch')
     51 # TRAIN
---> 54 history = model.fit(x_train, y_train)
     55 model.load_weights('fold-%i.h5' % fold)
     57 # PREDICT OOF

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68 finally:
     69   del filtered_tb

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py:1147, in func_graph_from_py_func.<locals>.autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145 except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146   if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147     raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148   else:
   1149     raise

TypeError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\dmartens\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\dmartens\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9956\295126875.py", line 10, in wcorr  *
        def wcorr(x, y): return tf_comp_metric(x, y ,w)
    File "C:\Users\dmartens\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9956\295126875.py", line 8, in tf_comp_metric  *
        def tf_comp_metric(a, b, w): return tf_cov(a, b, w) / tf.sqrt(tf_cov(a, a, w) * tf_cov(b, b, w))
    File "C:\Users\dmartens\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9956\295126875.py", line 7, in tf_cov  *
        def tf_cov(x, y, w): return (tf.reduce_sum(w * (x - tf.reduce_mean(x * w)) * (y - tf.reduce_mean(y * w))) / tf.reduce_sum(w))

    TypeError: `x` and `y` must have the same dtype, got tf.float32 != tf.int32.
```

Comment: Please add an example value for `X` and `fold` in order to make this a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Looks like a problem in loss function. Is it comparing after argmax ?

Comment: A shot in the dark: it might be that `asset_weight_dict[asset_name]` should also be a float instead of an integer

Comment: asset_weight_dict[asset_name] should have been a float. Didn't sanitize all my data. :facepalm: TYTY

Answer (score 0):

The problem was unrelated to `x_train` and `y_train`. mM weights were ints and not floats. Thanks [Ben Grossmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2476977/ben-grossmann) for [pointing that out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72205683/tensorflow-x-and-y-must-have-the-same-dtype-even-after-casting-to-the-corre/72205859#comment127574023_72205683).